# In the method addEventListener, how does passing a parameter x to anonymous function that implement console.log(x) can return the event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, anonymous-function, console.log

I don't understand how the `console.log(x)` works in the situation below.
I understand that `addEventListener("keydown", function)` means when keydown, do the function (here print to console).

However, I really can't grasp how things work when we pass a parameter to an anonymous function(here `x`) in method addEventListener(), then implementing console.log(x) will print the `keydown` event to console.

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(x) {
console.log(x); // e.g. KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "x", code: "KeyX", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
});
```

same with
(one small notice that with `event` I can just use `function()` and it's still working):

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function() { //here no need to input `event` as parameter
console.log(event); // e.g. KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: true, key: "x", code: "KeyX", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
});
```

but

```js
document.addEventListener("keydown", function() { //no parameter
console.log(x); // Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined
});
```

Comment: When you bind your element with the event, it passes the default **event** argument (this event type depends on the event) to the event method. Therefore even if you do not specify the parameter it passes it by default, if you want to change this argument name you must specify it.

Comment: The second case only works because browser's make the current event available via the global `event` variable. So in your second case, `console.log(event)` really is `console.log(window.event)`.  If you declare `x` outside of the event handler you will also be able to access it (though it won't refer to the event object of course).

Comment: @EngincanVeske: Yes, the event object is passed to the event handler, but that the fact that you don't have to specify a parameter is for different reasons.

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event): *"The read-only Window property event returns the Event which is currently being handled by the site's code. Outside the context of an event handler, the value is always undefined."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an event is fired, the function called gets the `Event` object passed to it as a parameter by default. In the first case, since your function's only parameter is `x`, it receives the `Event` object. In fact, it is equivalent to writing this:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
  var x = event;
  console.log(x);
});
```

In the second case, you are accessing the `Event` object directly via the `event` variable (i.e. not assigning it to another variable). In the third case, you are trying to access an undefined variable `x`, hence the error message.

Comment: I think you should elaborate on *"you are accessing the `event` object directly."*. It's not really clear what "direct access" means in this context. To illustrate my point: How would one "indirectly" access an object?

Comment: Sure, I will do.

Comment: *"i.e. not assigning it to another variable"* I think this is misleading. `event` is also a variable. What happens in the second case is that the *global variable* `event` is accessed, which happens to contain the current event object.

Answer (score 1):

Lets replicate these scenarios with our own logic, to better illustrate what's going on. I'm going to simplify things a little bit by directly invoking the callbacks, instead of waiting for an event. That doesn't have any impact on the things you are asking about.

#### Setup

Lets consider the following simple function which accepts and calls a callback:

```
function fire(callback) {
  callback(42);
}
```

as you can see, `fire` passes an argument to the callback.

That's what happens with the event handler as well: When the event triggers, the browser will call the event handler and pass the current event object to it.

#### First scenario

If a function defines a *parameter* it can access the arguments passed do it. So if I call `fire` as follows:

```
fire(function(x) {
  console.log(x);
});
```

Then my callback receives and logs `42`. I could choose any name for the parameter and it would work.

That's the same as in your first example: You are defining a parameter and decide to name it `x`. You could give it any other name.

#### Second scenario

In this example you are accessing the variable `event`. Because the variable is not defined inside the function and is not a parameter, it will be looked up in the outer scope (that's basically how closures work). Now, it so happens that `event` is a [global variable that refers to the currently handled event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event).

How would that work in our toy example? Imagine that `fire` assigns the value to a global variable first:

```
var globalArg;

function fire(callback) {
  globalArg = 42;
  callback(globalArg);
}
```

You can see that the value is made available as argument to the callback as well as the global variable `globalArg`. That's why both of these examples will work (corresponding to your first and second scenario):

```
fire(function(x) {
  console.log(x);
});

fire(function() {
  console.log(globalArg);
});
```

#### Third scenario

Similar to the second scenario, `x` is a variable that is neither defined inside the function nor is it a parameter. So the variable is looked up in the outer environment. However, it doesn't exist there either so an error is thrown.

Comment: hi, could you elaboratea bit more on the `function fire(callback) {  callback(42);}`? . I see that function fire passes the arg `callback`, but the code inside which is `callback(42)` doesn't do anything with the passed arg?

Comment: In this case, the parameter passed (i.e. `callback`) is a function. `callback(42)` calls that function with the argument 42.

Comment: thanks. I think I'm starting to get the grasp of it now. Why does `fire(function() {console.log(42); });` (notice there is no parameter `x`) still work? while   `fire(function() {console.log(43); });` is not working (Unexpected number) ?

Comment: @aanhlle: Both of those should work. You can pass any value to `console.log`.